# Is there a way to load turtle file directly from github?

Tags: graphdb

I currently store a turtle file in GitHub. I download that file and then upload it via the Import ->  Upload RDF files

I tried to upload it directly from GitHub using the 'Get RDF data from a url'. Didn't work. Am assuming this is not suited to be used in this way?

Comment: Did you use the raw.githubusercontent.com url rather than the typical github.com url? If not, I suggest you try that!

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse - I tried that. It gave me  'Connection timed out: connect' error

Comment: If possible, can you post a link to the triples? The link definitely resolves in your browser? In the raw.githubusercontent.com link, what's the file's extension?

Comment: This is the end of the github url master/file.ttl?token=ABBCADFKP67EMABODU5NUIRSLBG20524

Comment: My guess is that it's the auth token attached to it. I just tested the import feature with a public ttl and it worked fine. This may be a bug if query parameters are meant to be preserved. You can also check the source code for a more definitive answer as to what's happening with the URL.

https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-workbench/blob/0790b0de9657a49ea79b13192dd1a946998dce6e/src/js/angular/import/controllers.js#L478